# Store API data to state variable in react

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import * as actions from '../../../../core/actions';

function Earnings(props) {
    //state hooks
    // setEarnings will be use when we get data from API.
    const [earnings,setEarnings] = useState([]);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    //reducers.
    // initail state is empty object {}
    const earningsForSessionState = useSelector((state) => state.getEarningsReducer);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('111111111111 first use effect is running');
      let data = {
        "transaction_type":"multiple"
      }
       // calling API for getting data as an array.
        dispatch(actions.getEarnings(data));
    }, []);


    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log('2222222222 second use effect is running');
      console.log('', earningsForSessionState.payload?.success?.data?.data);
      //setEarnings(earningsForSessionState.payload?.success?.data?.data);
    }, [earningsForSessionState?.payload]);
}
```

I am able to print data in second useEffect which I got from API.
But I want to store that data to my state variable `earnings`.  As you can see I have commented `setEarnings` function in second useEffect function. But If I uncomment that line then I didn't get any data. I think I am using useEffect in wrong manner. Please tell me why am I not able to get data if uncomment `setEarnings` function in second useEffect.
I want to store API data to my state variable `earnings`. How do I do this ?

Comment: Storing duplicate state is anti-pattern in React, why do you need to store this redux state locally? Also, did you store an action object into state that includes the `payload` property?

Comment: Storing an action in the redux state looks awkward. Normally it's the data there, not the action. Use effect would normally be redundant, if you use the selector it automatically creates subscription to the store so that when store changes, component it rerendered.